# Убирать лишние атрибуты изображений при вставке в редакторе

Tags: wordpress

При создании записи, когда вставляем изображение в редакторе, то получается много лишних атрибутов:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-36" src="" alt="" width="578" height="407" />
```

Больше всего меня беспокоят width и height.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хук который будет убирать лишнее. Чтобы просто вставлялся чистый код img src.

Мне не нужно в итоговом отображении потом убирать лишнее, а хочется уже сразу в редакторе (в записи).

Comment: Если это делается через WYSIWYG, то [вот это](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-width-and-height-attributes-from-inserted-images/) должно сработать.

Comment: это очень дорогой метод. При сборке html этот фильтр будет применяться ко всей галереи изображений. Лучше так не делать. Хотя метод явно рабочий.

Comment: Да, @Simon, то что нужно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно так инициализировать если изображение из вашей темы.

```
<img class="header_logo__img" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/img.jpg" width="150" height="40" alt="logo site">
```

Если грузите из uploads для изображения записи. Страницы/поста, то так

```
$postID = $post->ID; // получить ID записи к чему привязано. Для поста
$img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postID);
```

а уже в html добавляете через.

```
<img src=<?php echo $img ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте класс к своему изображению. Например,

```
$arImg      = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'img', true );
$attr       = array(
    'class' => 'table-ico'
);
$img        = wp_get_attachment_image( $arImg, 'custom', false, $attr );
```